# KendoUI DropDownList Selects First Item without Interaction

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I've got a KendoUI DropDownList, it allows a user to search the server for results and select it from a list. Its an empty list until a search is made.

Currently after a search is made, the first result from the search is selected, even though the user never makes the selection. I'd prefer it to not make any changes unless a user actually makes a selection.

This example works as I would like, but I cannot get it to work the same in my own code. - http://dojo.telerik.com/EjUvu/3

```
    var control = $(matterControl).kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "DisplayName",
        dataValueField: "ID",
        minLength: 1,
        filter: "contains",
        value:'',
optionLabel: { DisplayName: 'Please enter 1 or more characters', ID: '' }, 
filtering:  function (e)  {
            var filter = e.filter;
            if (filter && !filter.value) { //prevent filtering if the filter does not value 
                e.sender.dataSource.data([]);
                e.sender.text('');
                e.sender.value('');
                e.preventDefault();
             }
         },
        autoBind: false,
        valuePrimitive: true,
        template:
        '<div class="searchResult">'+
        '<span class="searchTitle searchIcon" data-id="#:ID #" >#:DisplayName #</span>' +
                  '<span class="searchDescription">#:Description #</span></div>',
        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: (options) => {
                        var searchValue = options.filter
                            && options.filter.filters
                            && options.filter.filters[0]
                            && options.filter.filters[0].value;

                        var currentId = $(settings.entryIDField).val();
                        var currentText = $(settings.entryNameField).val();

                        if (currentId != null
                            && currentId !== undefined
                            && currentId !== emptyGuid
                            && !searchValue)
                            return defaultRoutes.SearchService.Search + "?searchText=" + currentText + "&recordId=" + currentId;
                        else 
                            return defaultRoutes.SearchService.Search + "?searchText=" + searchValue;
                    },
                }
            },
        }),
        select: function (e: any) {
            var  dataItem  =  this.dataItem(e.item); 
            $(settings.entryNameField).val(dataItem.DisplayName);
            $(settings.entryIDField).val(dataItem.ID);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Turns out he request might be more specific...

Is there a way to disable typing selections? The issue is that the selected item is being changed by the filter being entered, but its not obvious that this is happening to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you are describing is a limitation, that seems to be addressed already:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/1475

The upcoming 2016 R3 (somewhere in September) will include the fix.

I am not aware of a workaround for the current version that could prevent this from happening.